# Table View load more cell?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

trying to make a cell which loads more, but i cant get it to appear after the other cells, sorry for being vague but ill show you my code...

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [rows count] + 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *postCellId = @"postCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;

    cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:postCellId];

    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:postCellId];

    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    NSUInteger count = [rows count];

    if (row == count) {
        loadMore = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 30, 320, 25)];
        loadMore.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0 / 255.0 green:255.0 / 255.0 blue:255.0 / 255.0 alpha:1.0];
        loadMore.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"AvenirNext-Bold" size:18.0];
        loadMore.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:60.0 / 255.0 green:58.0 / 255.0 blue:55.0 / 255.0 alpha:1.0];
        loadMore.text = @"Load More...";
        loadMore.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:loadMore];


        displaying = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, 320, 25)];
        displaying.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0 / 255.0 green:255.0 / 255.0 blue:255.0 / 255.0 alpha:1.0];
        displaying.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"AvenirNext-Bold" size:12.0];
        displaying.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 115.0 / 255.0 green: 113.0/ 255.0 blue:112.0 / 255.0 alpha:1.0];
        displaying.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Displaying %i Results", rows.count];
        displaying.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:displaying];

    } else {

    dict = rows[indexPath.row];

    thumbimgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 80, 80)];
    businessLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(103, 10, 207, 25)];
    locationLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(103, 35, 207, 35)];
    locimgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(220, 75, 20, 15)];
    distanceLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(240, 75, 60, 15)];

    businessLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0 / 255.0 green:255.0 / 255.0 blue:255.0 / 255.0 alpha:1.0];
    businessLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"AvenirNext-Bold" size:18.0];
    businessLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:60.0 / 255.0 green:58.0 / 255.0 blue:55.0 / 255.0 alpha:1.0];
    businessLabel.text = dict[@"business"];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:businessLabel];

    locationLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0 / 255.0 green:255.0 / 255.0 blue:255.0 / 255.0 alpha:1.0];
    locationLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"AvenirNext-Regular" size:14.0];
    locationLabel.text = dict[@"location"];
    locationLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 115.0 / 255.0 green: 113.0/ 255.0 blue:112.0 / 255.0 alpha:1.0];
    locationLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
    locationLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeTailTruncation;

    [cell.contentView addSubview:locationLabel];

    listingLoc = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[dict[@"lat"] doubleValue] longitude:[dict[@"lon"] doubleValue]];

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    float kilometers = [appDelegate.currentLoc distanceFromLocation:listingLoc] / 1000;

    int milesint = kilometers * 0.621371192;

    NSString *milesOut = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i miles", milesint];

    distanceLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0 / 255.0 green:255.0 / 255.0 blue:255.0 / 255.0 alpha:1.0];
    distanceLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"AvenirNext-Regular" size:12.0];
    distanceLabel.textColor =  [UIColor colorWithRed:128.0 / 255.0 green:128.0 / 255.0 blue:128.0 / 255.0 alpha:1.0];
    distanceLabel.text = milesOut;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:distanceLabel];

    NSArray *splitImages = [dict[@"image1"] componentsSeparatedByString:@", "];

    icon = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[splitImages objectAtIndex:0]]]];

    [thumbimgView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
    [thumbimgView setClipsToBounds:YES];

    thumbimgView.image = icon;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:thumbimgView];

    locimgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"location-icon.png"];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:locimgView];

    cell.textLabel.text = dict[@"business"];
    cell.textLabel.hidden = YES;

    }

    return cell;
}
```

All it does is return the data from the array, and no cell is added after for the load more.. Many thanks.

Comment: Can you post some code from didselect row ?

Comment: Rows is working OK, i've NSLOG'd it, returning as it should.

Comment: It's like the return cell number isnt adding the 1, the indexpath only reaches the array count, not the array + 1.

Comment: The point is that you create a new cell regardless whether re-using was successful or not. That may leak memory at least. See my answer. It will fix this issue. It may not fix the issue that no more-cell is visible at all.

Comment: Not sure how the didselect... could cause this issue. Please go and NSLog the amount of count+1 in numberOfRowsInSection and NSLog indexPath.row (and again [rows count] in cellForRow... and have a look what really happens. And then get back to us.

Comment: NSLogged, 'NSLog(@"%i", [rows count] + 1);' and returns, 1, then 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    NSUInteger count = [rows count];
    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;    

    if (row == count) {
      // This is the bottom most cell, therefore display the More-Cell
      static NSString *postCellId = @"moreCell";

      cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:postCellId];
      if (cell == nil) {  // it cannot be re-used, so create a new one

         cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:postCellId];
         // now add all sub views such as labels and buttons. 
         // If the layout is always the same then you may set it here. 

      }
      // Now it is either re-used or newly created. However, it carries all the subviews. 
      // Here set the values. You may set the layout here too, if the layout depends on data.

    } else {
      // Display a regular Post-Cell    
      static NSString *postCellId = @"postCell";

      cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:postCellId];
      if (cell == nil) { // it cannot be re-used, so create a new one

         cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:postCellId];
         // now add all sub views such as labels and buttons. 
         // If the layout is always the same then you may set it here. 

      }
      // Now it is either re-used or newly created. However, it carries all the subviews. 
      // Here set the values. You may set the layout here too, if the layout depends on data.

    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Hermann, tried this, with the code, and its still not returning the bottom load more cell, just the rest, i think for some reason and extra cell isn't being added to display the data, the indexPath. When i put this 'NSLog(@"%i", indexPath.row);' it then logs: '0 0 1' in 3 lines. Any clues?

Comment: @RyanGittings, please go ahead and provide more debug data. Edit your question for that. NSLog the count in numberOfRowsInSection, and the current row in cellForRow... and NSLog the count again in cellForRow... so that we see whether [rows count] has changed in the meantime. Add the NSLog statements to the code in your question and provide the output within an edit to your question, so that everybody clearly sees what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a problem with the way you're implementing this. I simplified your code (mostly in the "else" clause) and created a dummy array, and everything worked fine. Notice that I am using the new paradigm for creating table view cells that makes it unnecessary to have the "if cell is nil" statement.

```
@implementation TableController {
    NSArray *rows;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"postCell"];
    rows = @[@"One",@"Two",@"Three",@"Four"];

}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [rows count] + 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"postCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    NSUInteger count = [rows count];

    if (row == count) {
        UILabel *loadMore = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 30, 320, 25)];
        loadMore.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0 / 255.0 green:255.0 / 255.0 blue:255.0 / 255.0 alpha:1.0];
        loadMore.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"AvenirNext-Bold" size:18.0];
        loadMore.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:60.0 / 255.0 green:58.0 / 255.0 blue:55.0 / 255.0 alpha:1.0];
        loadMore.text = @"Load More...";
        loadMore.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:loadMore];


        UILabel *displaying = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, 320, 25)];
        displaying.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0 / 255.0 green:255.0 / 255.0 blue:255.0 / 255.0 alpha:1.0];
        displaying.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"AvenirNext-Bold" size:12.0];
        displaying.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 115.0 / 255.0 green: 113.0/ 255.0 blue:112.0 / 255.0 alpha:1.0];
        displaying.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Displaying %i Results", rows.count];
        displaying.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:displaying];
    } else {
        cell.textLabel.text = rows[indexPath.row];
    }
    return cell;
}
```