# UITableView load more cells

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to add more cells when user scrolls to the end of list in table view.
I found this topic ([Table View load more cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14171414/table-view-load-more-cell)), but... is this OK to use "reloadData"? For example, we have 100 cell in table view, and for adding new 20 cells we will reload whole table view?

Comment: You you read any UITableView tutorials? They would answer this question.

Answer (score 4):

Esay to use :

1) Use `UIScrollView's scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` to find out if reached to last cell

```
 - (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
 {
    float offset = (scrollView.contentOffset.y - (scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height));
    if (offset >= 0 && offset <= 5) {
      // This is the last cell so get more data
      [self loadmore];
    }
 }
```

2) Now in load more method add object in your array or dictionary and in UITableView like this:

```
-(void)loadmore
{
   //add datasource object here for tableview
   [mutArrTblViewDataSourceHere addObject:anyDataObject];
   //now insert cell in tableview
   [yourtblViewObjectHere beginUpdates];
   [yourtblViewObjectHere insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[mutArrTblViewDataSourceHere count]-1 inSection:0]]withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
   [yourtblViewObjectHere endUpdates];
}
```

Comment: This is a good suggestion, but it would be better if you add the logic for loadMore() in "scrollViewDidScroll" method.                                               if offsetY > (contentHeight - scrollView.frame.size.height) {
            if shouldFetchNextPage == true {
                currentPage += 1
                
                loadMore()
            }
        }

Comment: Sorry for my above code for being written in Swift.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to reload the entire UITableView. You can just use `insertrowsatindexpath`

See this answer for reference. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6097835/1891327

Comment: No, you do not use `reloadRowsAtIndexPath` to add new rows. You use `insertsRowsAtIndexPaths:` to add new rows.

Comment: @rmaddy Yeah, sorry I miss typed. I was thinking of insertRowsAtIndex the whole time :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` method of UITableView to let UITableView know which rows are inserted.

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:

Answer (score 1):

After trying out Paresh's implementation - I found a cleaner solution for my own needs with UIScrollView's scrollViewDidScroll. The variable "lazyLoad" is a BOOL flag indicating whether or not an existing network request is happening.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    float offset = (scrollView.contentOffset.y - (scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height));

    if (offset >= 0 && offset <= 25 && !self.lazyLoad)
    {
        self.page++;
        [self loadReports];
    }
}
```